# hammerJs - Distinguishing between swipe and drag

Tags: hammer.js

How can swipe and drag be distinguished on the same element ? I tried:

```
Hammer(blueDiv).on('swipe', function(e) {
   e.gesture.stopDetect();
   e.gesture.preventDefault();
   alert('swipe');
});

Hammer(blueDiv).on('drag', function(e) {
   alert('drag');
});
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/crEEN/)

But when swiping I just get the alert for drag and not swipe.
What I need is just swipe event for a quick swipe, and just drag event for longer drag

any help ?

Comment: How would you differentiate between a drag and a swipe?

Comment: Are you suggesting that is the expected behavior ?

Hammer supports both drag and swipe so there must be a difference ...

To me a swipe is quick and covers little distance where as a drag is slower and covers a lot of distance.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it's not supported. I'm wondering how you would tell the difference when both are applied to the same element.

Comment: sorry I don't follow, why should it make a difference if it's the same element or not ? if drag and swipe are the same, what need is there for swipe at all ? and if they are different then they should be distinguishable also on a single element

Comment: My point is that both involve using your finger to touch an element and then to make a movement. Once touched, what criteria would you use to differentiate between a swipe and a drag? I know they are two different things and that the framework supports both but, on a single element, I'm curious as to how it would tell the difference.

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same challenge with the need to somehow distinguish swipe and drag events. What I see, the main criteria is so-called `velocity` of the move, which is set in options as `swipe_velocity` in [Hammer options](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started).

I tried to play with default `swipe_velocity` in Chrome, and noticed that if you do a move as if it were a swipe, i.e. touch => quickly drag => release, then it registers the event as `swipe` additionally to all the standard `touch`, `drag`, `release`. So I would suggest to catch `swipe` first then the rest events if needed.

Here is the function from Hammer that is in charge for calculating velocity, which makes things clearer:

```
  /**
   * calculate the velocity between two points
   * @param   {Number}    delta_time
   * @param   {Number}    delta_x
   * @param   {Number}    delta_y
   * @returns {Object}    velocity
   */
  getVelocity: function getVelocity(delta_time, delta_x, delta_y) {
    return {
      x: Math.abs(delta_x / delta_time) || 0,
      y: Math.abs(delta_y / delta_time) || 0
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Several problems with your attempt.

First, don't use alerts, try console.log and open up the dev tools on whatever browser you're using (F12). The alert box itself can make it hard to test what is actually going on when it pops up and gets in the way of the events.

Now, the bad news. You can't have a swipe without a drag. A swipe is a quick 'flick' of a motion, and your fiddle works just fine for that if you remove that drag alert. Since a swipe requires motion, by definition it will trigger a drag.

The good news, there are ways to work around it.

While you will not be able to avoid triggering the drag event without messing it up for when you actually want it, you can avoid acting upon it. What I would suggest is taking a look at event.gesture.velocity in your handler for the drag.

A simple if statement and you can avoid acting upon the drag if it's moving too fast.